# How to pass a string parameter which contains spaces into the shell script in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a string parameter in my Jenkinsfile which contains a space

parameters {
string(name: 'KW_Issue_resolution', defaultValue: 'Not a Problem', description: 'Marking the issue as Not a problem')
}

I am trying to pass this parameter into a shell script within a stage

```
stage ('Mark KW issues as not a problem') {
            
            steps {
                sh "kwcheck set-status ${params.KW_Issue_IDs} --status ${params.KW_Issue_resolution}"  
            }
         }
```

However, the shell doesn't recognize the entire string as "Not a Problem"

```
+ kwcheck set-status 190 --status Not a Problem
Cannot change status, 'Not' is not a valid status name
```

Expected the shell command to be kwcheck set-status 190 --status "Not a Problem"

Comment: I'd try putting `'` around `${params.KW_Issue_resolution}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable is interpolated in the Groovy interpreter with whitespace, the shell interpreter within the `sh` step method will not resolve it as a single argument string due to the delimiter. You can cast it as a literal string in the shell interpreter with the normal syntax:

```
sh "kwcheck set-status ${params.KW_Issue_IDs} --status '${params.KW_Issue_resolution}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use triple quotation marks in Groovy syntax.

So in triple quotation marks, you can use `"` and `'` like a native bash script.

```
    stage ('Mark KW issues as not a problem') {    
        steps {
            sh """#! /bin/bash
                kwcheck set-status "${params.KW_Issue_IDs}" --status "${params.KW_Issue_resolution}"
            """  
        }
    }
```